# PHPStorm 7 & Subversion Check File lock before opening file

Tags: svn, phpstorm

Is it possible with PHPStorm 7 to check if a file is locked in an subversion repository before it's getting openend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, doesn't work currently:( Please watch [IDEA-49011](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-49011) to be notified on any progress

Comment: Thanks it a shame it isn't build in yet :(